# Centripetal Force

Tags: forces, centripetal-force

What is the size of the force required to cause a car of mass $1.75\times10^3$ kg to travel 
in constant circle of diameter $25.0\space m$ with a constant speed of $25.0 \space ms^{-1}$ ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**:
We can use **Kinematics Equation** in Circular Motion to find **Centripetal Acceleration**,
Then the *acceleration multiplied by mass* will give us force required.

Hope this helps!